# How does $P(A) = P(A|B)P(B) + P(A|B^c)P(B^c)$ work?

Tags: probability-theory

So I'm trying to understand how $P(A) = P(A|B)P(B) + P(A|B^c)P(B^c)$ works intuitively, but everytime I try to visualize properties in venn diagrams, anytime a "given" pops up (i.e. $P(A|B)$, I can't figure out how to understand it.

Would really appreciate some help in understanding these, thanks in advance!

Comment: Recall that by using the definition of conditional probability, your equation is equivalent to $P(A)=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c)$, which is easier to visualize because $(A \cap B)\cup(A\cap B^c)=A$.

Comment: Oh yes, indeed, thanks that makes much more sense! @Snoop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of the "graphical" way to think about ${P(A | B)}$, it's easiest to actually expand the logic a bit and think of A and B as random objects that can take two possible values: 0 or 1.

Usually we see Bayes formula in the context of a propositions A and B, and it's given as:

${P(A | B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}}$

But in our context ${P(A | B)}$ is meaningless. Instead we need to be more specific and ask "What is the probability of ${A=1}$ given we know ${B=1}$?"

We now turn to the typical Venn Diagram (excuse the hastiness of the diagramm I threw together).

[image: Venn Diagram]

Recall that probabilities are typically scaled so that the total area of the figure is simply 1. However, pretend that the total area is actually something other than 1. How would we assess what **proportion** of the total area is taken up by ${P(A=1)}$?

We would sum together all the regions where ${A=1}$ — the orange region and the purple region — then we would have to divide by the *total area* of the figure. That is:

${P(A=1) =  \frac{P(A=1 \cap B=0) + P(A=1 \cap B=1)}{P(A=1 \cap B=0)+P(A=1 \cap B=1)+P(A=0 \cap B=0)+P(A=0 \cap B=1)}}$

Notice that the *total area* is the sum  of the orange region, purple region, lime region, and blue region. We often ignore this complex denominator because probabilities are scaled - for convenience - so that the denominator sums to 1.

Now we return to our question "What is the probability of ${A=1}$ given we know ${B=1}$?" Or rather what is ${P(A=1 | B=1)}$.

Since we know ${B=1}$, our *total area* is no longer the sum of all the colored regions. Instead we are in a new probability space where the total area is actually just the area of ${P(B=1)}$. Just like before if we want to know what is the probability of ${A=1}$, we need to sum all the areas where ${A=1}$ and divide by the total area.

What are all the areas where ${A=1}$? Since we are only in the universe of the circle where ${B=1}$, there is only one region — the purple region a.k.a ${P(A=1 \cap B=1)}$. And what is the new *total area* representing all possibilities? It is simply the sum of the purple region and the lime region a.k.a. ${P(A=1 \cap B=1) + P(A=0 \cap B=1)}$.

[image: Venn Diagram Bayes]

Hence, we have:

${P(A = 1 | B=1) = \frac{P(A=1 \cap B=1)}{P(A=1 \cap B=1) + P(A=0 \cap B=1)}}$.

And that's how I like to think about Bayes. Instead of plain 'ole ${P(B)}$ in the denominator, think of the denominator as the sum of all remaining possibilities based on the constraint you've been given. Written mathematically we can view it as:

${P(A=k | B=j) = \frac{P(A=k \cap B=j)}{\sum_i P(A=i \cap B=j)}}$

Answer (score 0):

To visualize a "given", you narrow your scope to only the parts of the diagram where the given are true.  That's what it means.  So $P(A|B)$ is the probability of $A$ if you restrict your attention only to $B$.

The statement says, "You can cut the possibilities into two pieces, those with $B$ true and those with $B$ false."  (aka those inside $B$ on the diagram and those outside.)

$P(A|B)\cdot P(B) = P(A \cap B)$, so the statement amounts to saying, "If $A$ is true, then either $A$ is true and $B$ is true, or $A$ is true and $B$ is false."

Comment: Thanks, so $P(A|B)$ would mean that we're only looking at the intersection? (when looking at a venn diagram)

Comment: Yes.  But multiplying by $P(B)$ means you are looking at the intersection of $A$ and $B$ when viewing the whole diagram.